# Developing Plugins / Add-in in Meteor Apps

Tags: meteor

Meteor Noob here not sure of all the terminology. If I had to build a Meteor app that can dynamically load Plugins/ Addin that gives specific function to my app.(something similar to Wordpress plugins) should I be packaging it as a Meteorite ?. If not, is there a design pattern that I can use ?

I apologize my search on stackoverflow or google did not give me any satisfactory results on this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should read: http://docs.meteor.com/#writingpackages and look at their packages source tree: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/ for examples.

Then if you want to publish your package you should package it as atmosphere package, the one-stop shop used by meteorite, more information about it can be found here: https://atmospherejs.com/docs/publishing